# How to retain select box value

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, jstl, jsp-tags

I had a select box. with 4 values(generating using jstl tags) and load button is there.

i am calling struts action on clicking load button

in struts action class i added `request.getAttribute("TA",value);`

now i want to retain the previous selected value in jsp page

```
                        <%if(request.getAttribute("TA")!=null && request.getAttribute("TA").equals("Cloud")) {%>
                            <option value='${i.thematicArea}' selected>${i.thematicArea}</option>
                        <%} else {%>     
                            <option value='${i.thematicArea}'>${i.thematicArea}</option>
                            <%} %>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </select>
                        </td>                   
                        <td><input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="Load"></td>
```

i want to compare with `${i.thematicArea}` instead of cloud. how to do that using jstl
ex:

```
request.getAttribute("TA").equals("Cloud")) 
instead of cloud i want to check with ${i.thematicArea}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One clean way is like this (uses the ternary operator which reduces it to a single line):

```
<select>

<c:forEach items="..." var="i">

   <option value='${i.thematicArea}' ${requestScope.TA == i.thematicArea ? 'selected' : ''}>${i.thematicArea}</option>

</c:forEach>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<c:if test="${not empty TA and TA eq i.thematicArea}">
  <option value='${i.thematicArea}' selected>${i.thematicArea} </option>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty TA or not TA eq i.thematicArea}">
  <option value='${i.thematicArea}'>${i.thematicArea}</option>
</c:if>
```

use this if you want to apply different markup on `option` tag.